# How to get multiple results from one webhook

Tags: rest, crm, webhooks, bitrix

I am developing a voice app for CRM software and tried to get information from multiple contacts.
The REST call I am supposed to use is:

```
https://xxxxxxxx.bitrix24.de/rest/1/secret_code/crm.contact.get
```

In the [documentation](https://training.bitrix24.com/rest_help/crm/contacts/crm_contact_get.php) it is stated that contact is returned with specified ID. For example, `https://xxxxxxxx.bitrix24.de/rest/1/secret_code/crm.contact.get?id=2` returns information of the contact with ID 2.

But is there a way for the call to return multiple results? i.e. I want to get information from contact with ID 2 and 4, is there a way to do this with a single webhook URL?

I tried `https://intranet_address.bitrix24.de/rest/1/secret_code/crm.contact.get?id=2&id=4` but it only returned the contact with ID 4. I am new to webhook so I have not much experience. Can anyone offer me some insight?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`batch`](https://training.bitrix24.com/rest_help/general/batch.php) query to call up to 50 rest-methods in one request

For your case (get two contact with ids 2 and 4):

```
curl -i -X POST \
   -H "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
   -d "cmd[q1]=crm.contact.get?id=2" \
   -d "cmd[q2]=crm.contact.get?id=4" \
 'https://xxxxxxxx.bitrix24.de/rest/1/secret_code/batch'
```

Response would be

```
{
  "result": {
    "result": {
      "q1": {
        "ID": "2",
        ...
      },
      "q2": {
        "ID": "4",
        ...
      }
    },
    "result_error": [],
    "result_total": [],
    "result_next": [],
    "result_time": {
      "q1": {
        "start": 1561537159.3722,
        "finish": 1561537159.3804,
        "duration": 0.0081892013549805,
        "processing": 0.0081391334533691
      },
      "q2": {
        "start": 1561537159.3805,
        "finish": 1561537159.3829,
        "duration": 0.0023989677429199,
        "processing": 0.0023589134216309
      }
    }
  },
  "time": {
    "start": 1561537159.3421,
    "finish": 1561537159.3829,
    "duration": 0.040737867355347,
    "processing": 0.010679960250854,
    "date_start": "2019-06-26T11:19:19+03:00",
    "date_finish": "2019-06-26T11:19:19+03:00"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is to invoke the `batch` REST method, which allows up to 50 commands in a single request.

It is unclear which language you're using. But if it's happened to be JavaScript or TypeScript, you can use [@2bad/bitrix](https://github.com/2BAD/bitrix) Bitrix24 REST API client to make it easier, as it will automatically batch and rate limit your commands, so you can pass in as many as you want commands:

```
import Bitrix, { Method } from '@2bad/bitrix'

const bitrix = Bitrix('https://PORTAL.bitrix24.ua/rest/1/WEBHOOK_TOKEN')

bitrix.batch([
  { method: Method.CRM_CONTACTS_GET, params: { ID: 2 } },
  { method: Method.CRM_CONTACTS_GET, params: { ID: 4 } }
  // add here as much as you want
] as const)
  .then((payload) => {
    const [deal2, deal4] = payload.result.result
    console.log('deal2:', deal2)
    console.log('deal2:', deal4)
  })
```